# Fundamental unit in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{-1})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to find the fundamental unit in $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{-1})$. I can show that $2 + \sqrt{3}$ is the fundamental unit in the intermediate field $k = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and that $\mathcal{O}_k^* $ and $\mathcal{O}_K^* $ both have rank $1$ by the Dirichlet Unit Theorem, so $2 + \sqrt{3}$ will generate some ring of finite index in $\mathcal{O}_K^* $. However I'm not sure how to go from this to finding the fundamental unit in $K$ since the tools I know of only work in the quadratic case. I've tried looking at the norm in $K$ to see if there is some quantity that is minimised for the fundamental unit but haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your field is the 12th cyclotomic field: $e^{2\pi i/12} = (\sqrt{3}+i)/2$.  Its ring of integers is $\mathbf Z[e^{2\pi i/12}]$ and the unit group of that ring of integers has fundamental unit $u = e^{2\pi i/12}-1$: the unit group is $\langle e^{2\pi i/12}\rangle \times u^\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Explicitly, $2+\sqrt{3} = e^{14\pi i/12} u^{-2}$, where $u = e^{2\pi i/12} - 1$ is a unit of infinite order.

Comment: How would you show $u$ is the fundamental unit in the 12th cyclotomic field?

Comment: Think about the extension $\mathbf Q(e^{2\pi i/12})/\mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})$, whose Galois group is the identity and complex conjugation, so for $\alpha \in \mathbf Q(e^{2\pi i/12})$ its norm down to $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})$ is $\alpha\overline{\alpha}$.  Compute this norm when $\alpha = u = e^{2\pi i/12} - 1$ as a first step.  You know that $u$ is a 12th root of unity times a power of an unknown fundamental unit. Use the norm calculation to show the exponent in that power is $\pm 1$, so $u$ itself has to be a fundamental unit.